# Add javascript to multiple specific urls

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm trying to add some javascript to my template.php file on a Drupal 7 site. I'd like the javascript to load on a specific set of pages, based on the url. For example, I'd like the script to load on:

mysite.com/blog/page1

mysite.com/blog/page2

but not on:

mysite.com

or
mysite.com/blog

or
mysite.com/about

I'm using

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = path_to_theme();
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  if($path == 'blog/page1') {
      drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/js/example.js');
    }
}
```

to load the script on that specific page, but is there any way to use a url argument or wildcard or something so that all internal blog pages (i.e. blog/page1, blog/page2, blog/page3) will load the script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`drupal_match_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7) function should do the trick:

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias();
$pattern = 'blog/*';

if (drupal_match_path($path, $pattern)) {
  drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/js/example.js');
}
```