# drupal_match_path() for multiple wildcard patterns?

Tags: 7, path-aliases, theming, javascript

I want to add some CSS and JS to multiple matched wildcard URL patterns. According to [Add javascript to multiple specific urls](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/48433/697), I can use a wildcard using [drupal_match_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7) and that works well for one pattern. However, I am trying to use a few patterns to add the same JS and CSS. So far I've tried these:

```
  // By path matching wildcard patterns.
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  $pattern = 'portfolio/* || photo-blog';
```

and

```
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  $pattern = 'portfolio/*, photo-blog';
```

and

```
  $pattern = 'portfolio/*' 'photo-blog';
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
```

... but none of these work. I am guessing it may not be possible in the context of:

```
if (drupal_match_path($path, $pattern)) {
// add JS and CSS based on above
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API page you've linked describes the format of the `$patterns` argument:

> $patterns: String containing a set of patterns separated by \n, \r or
>   \r\n.

These are types of carriage returns, in different Operating Systems.

Sooo .... did you try:

```
 $pattern = "portfolio/*\nphoto-blog";
 // or
 $pattern = "portfolio/*\rphoto-blog";
 // or
 $pattern = "portfolio/*\r\nphoto-blog";
```

EDIT:

```
 // for platform portability heh
 $pattern = "portfolio/*" . PHP_EOL . "photo-blog";
```

Answer (score 1):

This one got me *so* many times - `drupal_match_path()` is expecting a newline character to separate the paths. Add this function to your project and never look back:

```
function _get_path_pattern_string(array $items) {
  return implode(PHP_EOL, $items);
}
```

Example usage (overly verbose):

```
$patterns = array('portfolio/*', 'photo-blog', 'something-else');
$pattern_string = _get_path_pattern_string($patterns);
if (drupal_match_path($path, $pattern_string)) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Comment: hmmm ... `return implode(PHP_EOL, $items)'` ?

Comment: @tenken Yep stupid mistake, thanks for pointing that out